# Accessing SAP Pool Table A016 from Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sap-erp, sap-data-dictionary

We have two divisions in our company, one uses E1 on Oracle 11g the other uses SAP on Oracle 11g.

We also have a SQL Server system we use to data warehouse information once a night from both system to run our report server against.

The question I have is for **pooled tables** in SAP, such as `A016`, how would I get that information out of SAP?

Currently we have SSIS's setup with a linked server to the two Oracle servers which pull the data we need I just don't have the knowledge of SAP to find the Pooled tables.

if I can't pull the pooled tables because they don't physically exist is there a tool I can use in SAP to find out what tables the pooled table is getting it's information from? This way I can rebuild that table in SQL using a open query and some fun Joins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to access those tables using the application server.  They can't be accessed directly from the database.

You'll probably want to write an ABAP program to extract the data you need go from there.